# Use grub4dos to boot ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, grub4dos

I am using grub4dos 0.4.4 to boot Ubuntu 17.04 successfully. Here are lines in the file MENU.LST

```
title Ubuntu 17 (64bit)

fallback 6

find --set-root /iso/ubt1704.iso

map --mem /iso/ubt1704.iso (0xff) || map --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /iso/ubt1704.iso (0xff)

map --hook

root (0xff)

kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/iso/ubt1704.iso splash

initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

But for Ubuntu 18.04, they did not work. The computer restarted after menu Ubuntu 18.04 was selected.

Please help me to fix the problem. Thanks in advanced.

**Update on 15-Aug-2018.**

I have changed the content of MENU.LST as bellow and it worked.

```
find --set-root /iso/ubt1804.iso

map --mem /iso/ubt1804.iso (0xff) || map --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /iso/ubt1804.iso (0xff)

map --hook

root (0xff)

kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/iso/ubt1804.iso splash

initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

Comment: do you use the SAME line on your Ubuntu 18.04? if yes, your problem is pretty simple : ISO name (we see `ubt1704.iso`, so it must be `ubt1804.iso` for Ubuntu 18.04). Please add the current `MENU.LST`  that you re using with 18.04 if this is not an issue about ISO name

Comment: Please post your solution as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `grub4dos` to boot Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04 ISO disk image, here is the entry for the file `MENU.LST`:

```
title Ubuntu 18
  fallback 6
  find --set-root /iso/ubt1804.iso
  map --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /iso/ubt1804.iso (0xff)
  map --hook
  root (0xff)
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/iso/ubt1804.iso splash
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

NB,

- For Ubuntu 64bit from 14.04 to 17.10  `vmlinuz.efi` was used, so `kernel` has to be `/casper/vmlinuz.efi`, but
- For older versions and 18.04+ use `/casper/vmlinuz`
- For Ubuntu 32bit, it has always been `vmlinuz`
- For smaller ISO disk images, or your RAM is extremely big, you can use `--mem` for the `map` command to put the whole disk into system memory, like this:
  `map --mem /iso/smallcd.iso (0xff) || map --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /iso/smallcd.iso (0xff)`

Ref: [here](https://dev.to/suntong/grub4dos-to-boot-iso-disk-image-57ho)